# polygon popupContent did not get updated

Tags: polygon, leaflet, geojson

I have a $.getJSON function, which gives me a list of polygons and multipolygons, I am binding popups to each polygon like this

[inside the polygon loop]:

```
           var onEachFeature = function(feature, layer) {
              if (feature.properties && feature.properties.popupContent) {
                 layer.bindPopup(feature.properties.popupContent);
              }
           }  

            var polyStyle = {
                    "color": "#f2f2f2",,
                    "weight": 2,
                    "opacity": 0.5,
                    "fillColor": "#f2f2f2",
                    "fillOpacity": 0.4,
                    "radius": 8,
                    onEachFeature: onEachFeature
            };
            var geojsonFeature = {
                    "type": "Feature",
                    "properties": {
                        "name": feature_name,
                        "popupContent": feature_content //displays uniq data belongs to the polygon
                    },
                    "geometry": polyData
            };


    geojsonLayer = L.geoJson(geojsonFeature, polyStyle).addTo(map);
```

The popup contents on all the polygons display the same content, which is the content of the last polygon data in the loop. This is wrong, each popup content should show different data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm honestly surprised you're getting a popup at all. The `onEachFeature` function should be in the options of the `L.geoJson` object.

```
geojsonLayer = L.geoJson(geojsonFeature, {
    style: polyStyle,
    onEachFeature: onEachFeature
}).addTo(map);
```

The style only holds [styling options](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#path) inherited from the `Path` class. Also, in the code you provided, you have an extra comma after the color, and from what I can tell `radius` isn't a valid property unless you're creating a [circle](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#circle).

```
var polyStyle = {
        "color": "#f2f2f2",
        "weight": 2,
        "opacity": 0.5,
        "fillColor": "#f2f2f2",
        "fillOpacity": 0.4
};
```

The `onEachFeature` variable should actually be a function name that's called when creating the `L.geoJson` object. The rest looks okay, but you could probably just check if `feature.properties.popupContent` exists.

```
function onEachFeature(feature, layer) {

    if (feature.properties.popupContent) {
        layer.bindPopup(feature.properties.popupContent);
    }
}
```

[Here's a JSFiddle as an example.](https://jsfiddle.net/ianbroad/womjfxp4/)

Comment: Thanks. You helped me corrected the style option structure. But the problem is still there I suspect the problem might be MultiPolygon. Here is an example https://jsfiddle.net/yhe39rrn/1/

Comment: @AnnieC I don't actually see a problem. You only see 1 label because the polygons on the right side overlap perfectly - their geometry is identical. So, you aren't seeing the label for the bottom polygon, only for the top one. See this example: https://jsfiddle.net/ianbroad/yhe39rrn/2/ I made the top multipolygon have no fill, and you can see the other polygon's black fill underneath. Also notice the outline of the right polygon, see how it's darker? That's the 2 polygon's mixed together with the opacity. If you were to switch the polygon order in the geojson, you should see both labels.

Comment: @AnnieC here is the same example, but I switched the order of the features in the geoJson. I have the multipolygon first, and the polygon last. https://jsfiddle.net/ianbroad/yhe39rrn/3/

Comment: Thanks, your example works perfectly when polygon is placed after multipolygon in the geojson. The problem came back when adding more multipolygons though. I accept your answer, thanks!

Comment: @AnnieC is there a reason you're adding multiple polygons with identical geometry? You could work on getting the polygon and multipolygons in different layers, that way you could turn them on and off.

Comment: You are right, the identical geometry is the problem I have. I use L.control.layers and now I can see the problem very clear. thanks.